# bind a Queue into a DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows, forms, datagridview

I'm working on a Windows Forms Application using C#.
I've put a DataGridView in order to show the data that i've got from the database.
The DataGridView have 2 columns, and I want to bind a queue into each one of them.
I have 2 Queues, the 1st called "Verses" and the 2nd called "Chapters", and the DataGridView have 2 cells the 1st called "Verse" and the 2nd called "Chapter", now in order to bind the queues into the cells I have written this code:

```
Chapter.DataGridView.DataSource = Chapters.ToList();
Verse.DataGridView.DataSource = Verses.ToList();
```

When I run the application, the dataGridView rows number get changed to the number of cells in the queues, but it shows no data inside, it's only empty cells.

Here's a picture for the Form, and the dataGridView is selected:

[image]

Here's the Queues:

```
Queue<string> Chapters; 
Queue<string> Verses;
```

Here's the DataGridView Columns.
[image]

Comment: `The DataGridView have 2 cells` <---- This doesn't make it clear on what structure your DataGridView has. 2 Cells on the same column or 2 cells on the same row? You should make it clear with some example.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. You are sayinh that there is one DataGridView but I see two of them - `Chapter.DataGridView` and `Verse.DataGridView`. Another thing - how it comes the Chapter and Verses are queues? Why do you load data from a database to a queue? Please, post at least image of your form.

Comment: I'm sorry but I wrote something wrong, I meant to say columns instead of cells.

Comment: @MohamedGooner looks like you have 2 DataGridViews, one is `Chapter.DataGridView` and the other is `Verse.DataGridView`? it's so confusing.

Comment: I have 1 DataGridView, and in it there's 2 columns, each column has its identifier, and in each column I want to import a queue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this:

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = 
 Chapters.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
         .Join(Verses.Select((x, i) => new { x, i }), 
               x => x.i, x => x.i, 
              (x, y) => new {Chapters = x.x, Verses = y.x}).ToList();
```